# How to allow unlimited number of names for input?

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "ReadString.h"


    void main()
    {
        int     i ;
        int     NumNames=5;
        char ** pNames;
         int MaxNum = 10;
        int more(0);

        pNames = new char *[NumNames];


        cout << "Enter  names" << endl;
```

This is the part where I am having trouble. I tried in different way but didn't work out. I tried to make a loop unless the first character is an 'Enter Key'.

```
while(cin.get()!='\n')
{
        for (i = more; i < NumNames; i++)
        {

                cout << (i + 1) << ") ";
                pNames[i] = ReadString();

                more = NumNames;
                NumNames +=NumNames
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, some of the variable are of not use. I forgot to delete them :)

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" (or something similar) then you next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also, stop using old C-style strings using pointers or arrays, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace manually allocated dynamic array with some container which can grow dynamically, for example `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::string name;
// read the names
while (cin >> name) {
    names.push_back(name);
}
```